# filter for unique words count with Stream <String> stream = Arrays.stream(words);

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create a one liner which should count unique words from a very long text file. Unique words are for example: márya fëdorovna scarlet-liveried,... so basically all non english words.

My problem is that with my code I filter not enough words. 
My code:

```
    String text = readText("longlongtextfile"); // My own method for readText
    String[] words = text.split(" ");

    System.out.println("Initial word count: " + words.length);                                                              

    Stream <String> stream = Arrays.stream(words);
    long uniqueWords = stream.map(String::toLowerCase).distinct().count();

    System.out.println(uniqueWords);
```

I wanted to apply the .filter(i -> i >= 'a' && i <= 'z').distinct().count() but that does not work for a String Stream.

So my question is, if there is a similar a-Z filter for a String Stream

Comment: do it before creating stream

Comment: What is the purpose of filtering on `a`-`z` when you explicitly say your text includes non-ASCII words? Or do you actually mean that you want `márya` and `Marya` to be considered the same word, i.e. ignore case and accents?

Comment: hmmm, I wanted to ignore all a-z words and count only the unique ones like márya, but maybe I am mixing up stuff already with this streams

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi not sure where before creating the stream I should do it.. and I don't want to create methods

Comment: i mean before this line `Stream <String> stream = Arrays.stream(words);`  modify your words , clean them from numbers or smilies or ...  using `regex` , then use the Stream and etc ...

Comment: yap, regex is a good thing to start with, thaanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To count words that contain characters other than `a-z`, you could filter using a regex:

```
Arrays.stream(tokens).map(String::toLowerCase).filter(t -> !t.matches("[a-z]+")).distinct().count();
```

To find the number of unique tokens you'll need to count the number of times they occur:

```
long uniqueWordCount = Arrays.stream(tokens)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    // Build a map from word -> frequency
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()))
    // stream the frequency map entries
    .entrySet().stream()
    // filter to retain unique words (with frequency == 1) 
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
    // count them
    .count();
```

Comment: thank you, I think this is what I was looking for, I still don't have the final count I needed, but this definitely helped! Will read more about regex

Comment: I've added a one-liner for counting unique tokens to the answer.